# How to get rid of ducks

Tags: pests, damage

I need about 25 ducks gone. They're destroying my landscaping. What and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: I think it is very difficult. So take it as the weather: never ideal, but you cannot change it. So use them in your favour, and contain them in a small part: make a part of your garden very favourable to them, and the other part no. This will reduce their raids. And felines in this case could help: ducks will prefer not to go in the open part of your garden.

Comment: This similar question on geese may offer more insights. https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13606/is-there-a-way-i-can-deter-geese-from-visiting-my-yard-and-pond